# Sublime Text sidebar initial view scrolled to end of longest filename

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext4

When I open Sublime Text, the sidebar view is scrolled-right to the maximum-length filename in the sidebar file tree.

Previously, the sidebar view always opened to the default view of left-alignment.

This is a recent phenomenon; neither my user settings nor packages (and their user-settings) have changed.

How can I restore the "default" left-aligned sidebar view?

```
Sublime Text
Stable channel, build 4143
```

[image: Reference screenshot of fresh boot subl]

Comment: What build number are you running?

Comment: It's in the reference image but let me put it in the post too: `Stable channel, build 4143`

Comment: Sorry, my bad; I was focused more on the sidebar part of that.